# UIImageView Resize and Rotate issue using Erica Sadun example - prepopulate location

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

I am using the example by Erica Sadun for how to resize and rotate a `UIImageView`: https://github.com/erica/iphone-3.0-cookbook-/tree/master/C08-Gestures/14-Resize%20And%20Rotate

It is a wonderful example and exactly what I am wanting, but it falls short in one area. I cannot figure out how to pre-populate the transform property of the `UIImageView` so that I can save the state of the image and load it back into a view later, with the same position, scale and rotation.

Currently every time I add the `UIImageView` subclass it starts in the top left corner of the screen, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to pre-populate the `transform` property so it doesn't so that.

When the image is created, we do:

```
originalSize = self.bounds.size;
originalTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
touchBeginPoints = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);// could this be the issue?
```

The subclass contains a lot of code, so I am not sure it should be reposted in its entirety.

Anyone used this before and could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGAffineTransformIdentity is a blank transform and won't do anything.

You need to set its transform to the transform you created.

Comment: Ha, you are right. I know it seems obvious, but I think I was digging a little too deep to find the problem. This fixed it, thank you!

Comment: No problem sometimes it takes a extra pair of eyes :)